# mat-drawer opened doesn't update with MediaObserver

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

Before open an issue, I'd like to know if there is something wrong 
with this code.

The problem is using the toggle device toolbar in chrome (from lg to xs) the mat-drawer is still open. If I do refresh it works fine.

### view

```
<mat-drawer-container>
  <mat-drawer
    #drawer
    class="sidenav mat-elevation-z1"
    mode="side"
    [opened]="opened"
  >
    <admin-layout-nav></admin-layout-nav>
  </mat-drawer>
  <main><router-outlet></router-outlet></main>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

### ts

```
opened = true;
constructor(private media: MediaObserver) {
  let watcher = media.media$.subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
    let activeMediaQuery = change
          ? `'${change.mqAlias}' = (${change.mediaQuery})`
          : '';
    if (change.mqAlias == 'xs') {
      this.opened = false;
    }
  });
}
```

### RESOLVED

```
[opened]="opened$ | async"

this.opened$ = media.media$.pipe(
      map((change: MediaChange) => {
        if (change.mqAlias == 'xs') {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      })
    );
```

Comment: any reason why you don't use the basic approach? https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API. you could use show and hide of certain elements at certain breakpoints.

Comment: Because of in large screen onload I want to show it and in the xs screen hide it but still using it :)